# Can Android turn the mobile access point on automatically on my home?

Tags: mobile-data, google-maps

I share almost always my mobile data to my laptop because I like to use faster web as my home offers. Is there a way on Android 7.0 such that it turns and keeps the mobile access point on if I am near enough my home whose coordinates are fixed?

Comment: Can you check in *Settings* if your device supports "profiles"? If so, you could configure a profile that checks if your home WiFi is connected and switches on the hotspot then. If you rather want to do that via "location", you'd probably need some [tag:automation] app.